# How to publish a Vb.net application with crystall report, without client install the visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've problem with my application project, I decide to setup my VB.Net application to exe file so I can just tell the client to setup my application in their device and connect to my PC to get the database (Xampp Mysql). I don't want to make client install the MySQL ODBC Driver, Crystal Report,and Visual Studio instead they just need to setup my exe file.

actually I already make the client connect to the database, but because my application have a crystal report on it, it's making more complicated.

My tool:

- Visual Studio 2022
- Installer Project for VS 64 bit
- Crystal Report for VS 2022 64 bit
- Xampp
- Odbc Data sources 64 bit and 32 bit
- my sql driver 64 bit and 32 bit

this is the module that will process the database connection, I use mysql in Xampp, and to connect it I use Mysql ODBC Driver 64 bit :

`

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Module Module1
    Public Conn As OdbcConnection
    Public da As OdbcDataAdapter
    Public ds As DataSet
    Public rd As OdbcDataReader
    Public rd2 As OdbcDataReader
    Public cmd As OdbcCommand
    Public cLevelUser, cUserId, mPath, cNamaUser, cId_Dataset, cKode_Prodi, cId_Periode As String
    Public tblEdit, Valid As Boolean
    Public Sub Koneksi()
        'Procedure koneksi database dengan MySql
        mPath = Application.StartupPath & "\"
        Try
            Conn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=dsnMahasiswa_Regis;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
            If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                Conn.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Koneksi Database Gagal", vbExclamation, "Koneksi Gagal")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Function StripNonAlphaNum(ByRef sText As String) As String
        Dim strRegex As String = "[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]"
        Dim rgx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(strRegex)
        Return rgx.Replace(sText, "")
    End Function
    Public Function SHA256(ByVal Content As String) As String
        'Function untuk mengenkrip password dengan algoritma SHA256
        Dim MoleCul3 As New Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim ByteString() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Content)
        ByteString = MoleCul3.ComputeHash(ByteString)
        Dim FinalString As String = Nothing
        For Each bt As Byte In ByteString
            FinalString &= bt.ToString("x2")
        Next
        Return FinalString
    End Function
End Module
```

`

this is when I run in Client (**without** Vs 2022 and without Crystal Report)
[unexpected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiv5v.png)
and
this is my expected result, my device(Server **with** vs 2022 , Xampp, Crystal Report ,etc) POV :
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBjAb.png)

Comment: If you want to use crystal reports in an environment that does not have VS installed, you need to install the corresponding version of the Crystal reports runtime framework.

Answer (score 0):

Install the **Crystal runtime** (no need for Visual Studio) on the user's machine.

Be sure to deploy the runtime with a service pack level matching the service pack level of your CR for VS.

Comment: Hello @MilletSoftware, thank you for your response. your suggest still not solve the issues, I have install the CR runtime unfortunately the same error still appear. maybe you have some reference where should I download it

Answer (score 0):

The downloads are here: https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html

Be sure to pick the Runtime (in the green box) -- not Cr for VS (in the red box).

Be sure to use the same SP level as the one used in your project in Visual Studio.

Be sure to use the same 32/64 bit choice as your compile target in the project.

[image]